# OpenShift MySQL failed to attach volume

Tags: mysql, openshift, persistent-volumes

I have a small Python Flask server running on OpenShift starter us-west-1. I use a MySQL container for data storage. Yesterday I scaled down the MySQL application from 1 to 0 pods. When I tried to scale it back up to 1 pod, the container creation keeps failing when trying to mount the persistent volume:

> Failed to attach volume "pvc-8bcc2d2b-8d92-11e7-8d9c-06d5ca59684e" on node "ip-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX.us-west-1.compute.internal" with: Error attaching EBS volume "vol-08b957e6975554914" to instance "i-05e81383e32bcc8ac": VolumeInUse: vol-08b957e6975554914 is already attached to an instance status code: 400, request id: 3ec76894-f611-445f-8416-2db2b1e9c5b7

I have seen some suggestions that say that the deployment strategy needs to be "Recreate", but it is already set like that. I have tried scaling down and up again multiple times. I have also tried to manually stop the pod deployment and start a new one, but it keeps giving the same errors.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you also trying to use the same persistent volume claim with another application, such as your front end web application. You can't do that with EBS volume types as they can only be mounted on one node at a time and there is no guarantee that your database and front end would run on the same node.

Comment: I only use the volume for the MySQL database. I don't have a front-end and the server for the API doesn't use the volume. It connects with the database to store and retrieve data. I have even tried scaling down the server and I still get the same error even though the database is the only pod.

Comment: You may be affected by current issues with the platform, although it sounds like the volume is just stuck. In case it is the latter, you can use support link for Online Starter under https://www.openshift.com/about/contact.html Otherwise monitor the status pages for the cluster for resolution on issues known to be affecting the platform at https://status.starter.openshift.com/

Comment: Ok, I will contact support and see if that's the case.

Comment: When you create a community support ticket, is there a way to see it's status? I received an email with an id that I can reply to with additional info. Is there a website where I can check it's status?

Comment: Does the email not include a link? I created one once a long time ago to work out where it went, but I can't remember what was in the response.

Comment: The email says:
Thank you for contacting OpenShift Online, Your request has been received and is being reviewed by our Community Enablement team.
To add additional comments, reply to this email.

Below that there is only one link "Developer Community" that goes to stackoverflow.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After contacting support, they fixed the volume and recently also updated the platform to prevent this bug in the future.